# Is the set of multiple points of the Brownian path $W[0, \infty)$ dense in the plane almost surely?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $d = 2$. With probability $1$, is the set of multiple points of the Brownian path $W[0, \infty)$ dense in the plane?

Comment: This is a homework exercise, please do not respond

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- Dvoretsky, Erdos and Kakutani 1954

https://books.google.com/books?id=onG8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=multiple+points+of+the+Brownian+motion+dense&source=bl&ots=vxQ1n_EC4t&sig=wnDVnqRcN8F1WdCrriGTU-k3GJU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwB2oVChMI8cmcvLPayAIVAeBjCh10ewye#v=onepage&q=multiple%20points%20of%20the%20Brownian%20motion%20dense&f=false