# In the plane, does complement of Brownian path have infinitely many connected components?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, brownian-motion

Let $d = 2$. Do we have that with $P_x$—probability $1$, for every $T> 0$ the complement $W[0, T]^c$ of the Brownian path up to time $T$ has infinitely many connected components?

I had seen this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221693/is-the-set-of-multiple-points-of-the-brownian-path-w0-infty-dense-in-the-p), and I was wondering if this result is also covered in the 1954 Dvoretsky/Erdos/Kakutani paper. If not, can somebody provide me a reference/supply an answer?

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494120/in-the-plane-does-complement-of-brownian-path-have-infinitely-many-connected-co

Comment: This is a homework exercise, please do not respond

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Just observe that

(1) on any fixed time interval the Brownian path intersects itself with positive probability (easy to see);

(2) but the above implies that on any time interval the Brownian path intersects itself with probability 1 (divide that interval into many sub-intervals and use the Markov property);

(3) so, with probability 1 in any neighbourhood of a fixed point on the Brownian path there will be at least one connected component of the complement, and this implies the claim.

Comment: Why  is (1) "easy to see"?

Comment: By conformal invariance, this probability must be the same for all intervals (consider the time interval $[0,c]$; then the mapping $z\mapsto z/\sqrt{c}$ sends the trajectory on $[0,c]$ to trajectory on $[0,1]$). I think it's evident that the Brownian trajectory on the time interval $[0,1]$ intersects itself with positive probability.

Comment: In dimensions $\geq 4$ a.s. a  Brownian path will not have self-intersections  according to Dvoretsky, Erdos and  Kakutani. The fact that the dimension is $\leq 2$ must enter the argument. I don't see where you used the information about dimension in your argument.

Comment: Step 3 should have an argument, too, to rule out something like a space-filling curve that intersects itself a lot but which has empty complement.

Comment: A proof  of the existence of self-intersections in dimensions  $\leq 3$ can be found in  Sec. 9.3 of  Morters  and Peress' book  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/peres/brbook.pdf

Comment: Douglas Zare, but it's known that a BM's trajectory doesn't hit any fixed point a.s., so the complement is clearly dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I agree that instead of just "intersects itself" better write something like "goes around a small ball".

Comment: "I don't see where you used the information about dimension in your argument." - here: "I think it's evident that the Brownian trajectory on the time interval $[0,1]$ intersects itself with positive probability."